# find an ants speed using calculus

Tags: calculus

I had this problem in my homework and I don't know what to do to do to start this whole thing.

The velocity v(t) of an ant that is moving along the t−axis is given by:
$v(t)=−\frac{3t}{(23+t^2)^{3/2}}$

The position $s(t)$ of the ant at time $t=0$ is $28$. What is $s(t)$ at time t?

I am thinking that i definitely need to take the integral of the velocity so i got $\frac{3}{\sqrt{t^2+23}}+C$ but I don't know what to do next can can anyone help with this?

Comment: You can evaluate the value of $C$ by using the fact that $s(0)=28$

Comment: I found the C to be 641/23 what do I do now?

Comment: Please format your equations using MathJax ... [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: You plug the value of $C$ in the equation and you have your expression of $s(t)$ :)

Comment: i got 3/sqrt(t^2+23)+641/23 and its saying thats wrong why?

Comment: Recheck your calculation for $C$. When you solve $28 = s(0)$, that is $$28 = \frac{3}{\sqrt{0^2+23}}+C$$ I get $$C= -\frac{3}{\sqrt{23}}+28 \approx  27.3745$$

Comment: You might find it more intuitive to say: $s(t) =  \int_0^t v(t) dt + s(0)$

Comment: It's exactly the problems of this sort we have in mind when we are talking about "applied mathematics" $\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take the integral, $$ s(t) = \int_0^t v(x) \mathrm{d}x + 28 $$

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what @Doug M said..